# Summation of $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^k = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $z$ doesn't equal $1$ and $z^n=1$ for some integer $n>1$. Show that:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^k = 0$$

I'm completely stuck on this.  Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: its a property of the product $0=Z^n-1=(z-1)(z^{n-1}+\cdots+z+1)$, since
$z\neq 1$ you have the desired!

Comment: Let $S = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} z^k$.  Then
$$zS = \sum_{k=1}^{n}z^k = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}z^k +1= S$$

Comment: @Macavity I really like that! $zS=S$ implies either $z=1$ or $S=0$, but we know $z \neq 1$, so $S=0$.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: $z^n-1=(z-1)(z^{n-1} + z^{n-2}+...+z+1)=0$

Answer (score 1):

HINT :
$$z^n-1=(z-1)(z^{n-1}+z^{n-2}+\cdots +z^2+z^1+1).$$